# Xcode - Restore Snapshot - File does not exist in restore location

Tags: xcode4, snapshot

When I tries to Restore Snapshop, the right pane instead of highlighting the changes, comes up with the message 'Files does not exist in restore location'. Then, even i clicks 'restore', nothing changes. But if i go to Organizer-Projects, the snapshots are there and I can export it and restore from there. Guess i can do it that way, but it's more convenient to restore to the original location.

I'm running XCode 4.6.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Same problem on Xcode 5. My project folder is SVN versioned, I guess this may be confusing Xcode, but I am not sure. Is this your case as well?